# How to generate same matching rules for "arrayMinLike' using lambda Dsl for Pact?

Tags: lambda, pact, pact-jvm

I have a sample body as below;

```
[
  "01/01/2019",
  "01/02/2019",
  "01/03/2019"
]
```

I'd like to validate the following:
1. The response should be an array with **at least 1 element**
2. Each element should be:
  2.1. String
  2.2. Should be in this format "DD/MM/YYYY"

It works perfectly fine with the "old" style:

```
DslPart body = PactDslJsonArray.arrayMinLike(1, 2, PactDslJsonRootValue.stringMatcher(Constants.DATETIMEPATTERN, "01/01/2019"));
```

This would generate pact file with matching rules as below. Notice the `$` and `$[*]`

```
...
                "matchingRules": {
                    "body": {
                        "$": {
                            "matchers": [
                                {
                                    "match": "type",
                                    "min": 1
                                }
                            ],
                            "combine": "AND"
                        },
                        "$[*]": {
                            "matchers": [
                                {
                                    "match": "regex",
                                    "regex": "^(([0-3]?\\d+)\\/((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\\/20\\d{2})$"
                                }
                            ],
                            "combine": "AND"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

However, when I try with the "new" style, which is **lambda Dsl for Pact (Java8)**, it doesn't generate the same matching rules; hence doesn't work the same way and my provider test always fails with the below error message

> $ -> Expected a List with 1 elements but received 3 elements

Below is the code and the matching rules that my code generate. Notice the `$[0]` and `$[1]`:
Matching rules

```
...
"matchingRules": {
                    "body": {
                        "$[0]": {
                            "matchers": [
                                {
                                    "match": "regex",
                                    "regex": "^(([0-3]?\\d+)\\/((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\\/20\\d{2})$"
                                }
                            ],
                            "combine": "AND"
                        },
                        "$[1]": {
                            "matchers": [
                                {
                                    "match": "type",
                                    "min": 1
                                }
                            ],
                            "combine": "AND"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And the code

```
DslPart body = newJsonArray((array) -> {
    array
            .stringMatcher(Constants.DATETIMEPATTERN, "01/01/2019");
}).minArrayLike(1).build();
```

Tried another way

```
DslPart body = newJsonArray((array) -> {
    array
            .stringMatcher(Constants.DATETIMEPATTERN, "01/01/2019")
            .minArrayLike(1);
}).build();
```

I've been trying to place the `.minArrayLike(1)` in different places but none of them works. Is there anyway to produce the same matching rules using lambda Dsl for Pact?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Please see the problem and the solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56713704/pact-dsl-provider-returning-more-records-than-in-pact-file)

eg:-

```
final DslPart actualPactDsl = LambdaDsl.newJsonBody((bodyDsl) -> {
            bodyDsl
                    .stringType("id", "1")
                    .stringType("name","Dep 1")
                    .minArrayLike("students",1,(stud) ->{
                        stud
                            .stringType("id","1")
                               .stringType("firstName","John")
                               .stringType("lastName","Smith")
                               .numberType("age",21);
                    });

        }).build();
```